# Figure/animation creation in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, programming, animations

What is one of the most complex/difficult figures that was created entirely in LaTeX? Is it possible to draw the globe figure that one can see here on TEX in the background just above the "Ask Question" button? What about this Lord Of The Rings style writing on the left of the "TEX" title above? Is it possible to do animations in LaTeX like some view of the Solar system?

Comment: Some view of the solar system? If you mean like a 3d model, it's not worth it.

Comment: all the banner text was generated in tex, there is an answer with the code somewhere

Comment: some of it is discussed here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup/641#641